# Integrating Admob into Unity 3d Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, unityscript

I am developing a game in unity 3d. My problem in this game is that I am unable to integrate admob. I tried so many tutorials and followed many blogs but no result.

Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Failed to compile resources with the following parameters:
-bootclasspath "/Users/Kishan/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar" -d "/Users/Kishan/Desktop/TestAds/Temp/StagingArea/bin/classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding UTF-8 "com/avalondev/ProductName/R.java" "com/google/android/gms/R.java"

Comment: error building Player: UnityException: Resource compilation failed!
Failed to recompile android resource files. See the Console for details.

Comment: above two are error messages am getting while integrating

Comment: Edit that into your question. And by all means include your own relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Update your android sdk to latest version
2. copy "android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib" this folder to your "Assets\Plugins\Android" folder
3. Update/Check your AndroidManifest.xml (min, max, targetsdkversion)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the old AdMob or the new system? If you are using the new systemm you must have Google Play Center downloaded in your Android SDK. Also make sure that you have the java jdk installed and your user path is updated. Here is a good guide on how to do it:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/828689/resource-compilation-failed-failed-to-recompile-an.html

Comment: Thanks for reply, am unable to run this command open ~/.bash_profile showing bash profile doesn't exist